# jQuery recursively remove empty children

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have a nested set of html  tags and i want to delete all  tags and their children without text.

**Example:**

```
<div id="mydiv">

<span></span>
<span><br></span>
<span> <span><br></span> </span>
<span>   <span><br> <span></span> </span>  </span>

<span> <img src="someimg.jpg" width="100" height="100"> </span>
<span>some text</span>

</div>​
```

So i want spans with images and text to stay and others leave.

**I need that result after my function**:

```
<div id="mydiv">

<span> <img src="someimg.jpg" width="100" height="100" /> </span>
<span>some text</span>
</div>​
```

I figured out, this is to be done recursively either by JavaScript or jQuery with its' method .children()
here is my code i wanted to use, but i can't figure how to build recursion:

```
 var remove_filter = function () {
            children= $(this).children();

            for (var i = -1, l = children.length; ++i < l;) {
                if ($(children[i]).text() == "") {
                    $(children[i]).remove();
                }
                //may be recursion here
                //else if(){
                //}
            }
            return $(this).text() == "" && $(this).children().length == 0;
}
$('#mydiv').find('span').filter(remove_filter).remove();
```

This code is broken, it deletes  and leaves empty spans...
How an i gain my result with recursion?

**EDITED**

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EGVQH/

**EDITED 2 time**

I found a bug in the right answer, but it is small. If i have code like this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<span> <br> Some text</span>
<span>   <span><br> <span></span> </span>  </span>

<span> <img src="someimg.jpg" width="100" height="100"> </span>
<span>some text</span>

</div>​
```

I assume it to result in:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<span> Some text</span>
<span> <img src="someimg.jpg" width="100" height="100" /> </span>
<span>some text</span>
</div>​
```

previous "Correct" answer to my question was giving wrong result at `<span> <br> Some text</span>`. Other answers were wrong after testing a bit.

See my JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EGVQH/2/

Comment: does it HAVE to be recursive?

Comment: i think it should be. because nesting level could be up to 10-20 elements, so 20+ "for" circles are bad:)

Comment: if an element doesn't have innerText, none of its children have either, so after testing for images the top parent can be safely removed without checking children.. or what am i missing here?

Comment: can you show your suggestion in the answer please? you can test it in my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EGVQH/

Comment: So is the only "permitted" element an `<img>` element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function rem(root) {
    var $root = $(root);
    $root.contents().each(function() {
        if (this.nodeType === 1) {
            rem(this);
        }
    });

    if (!$root.is("area,base,col,command,embed,hr,img,input,keygen,link,meta,param,source,track,wbr") && !$root.html().trim().length) {
        $root.remove();
    }
}


rem("#mydiv");​
```

Using on:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<span> <br> Some text</span>
<span>   <span><br> <span></span> </span>  </span>

<span> <img src="someimg.jpg" width="100" height="100"> </span>
<span>some text</span>

</div>​
```

Leaves:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<span>  Some text</span>


<span> <img src="someimg.jpg" width="100" height="100"> </span>
<span>some text</span>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LEKaL/1/

Comment: seems to be it more likely. I will test it and then accept tomorrow if it passes tests.

Comment: @Feanor have updated it, it should be .contents() instead of .find. (the difference is that find will probably crash with bigger depth :D)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, without recursion, using each, check for non text containing tag also, like img

```
$(function(){
    $('#mydiv').find('span').each(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        if($.trim(self.html())==""){
            self.remove();
        }else if($.trim(self.text())=="" && self.has('img').length ==0)
            self.remove();
    });
});
```

you can change `$(this).has('img').length ==0` for input, iframe or any other non text containing tags like `$(this).has('img, input, iframe').length ==0`

Comment: You should use $.trim() instead of .trim() - it will break in IE

Answer (score 2):

This is a very quick and dirty way of solving your problem

```
$('#mydiv span br').remove();
while($('#mydiv span:empty').length > 0){
    $('#mydiv span:empty').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. But this will remove image as well. You need to add condition to not remove image.

```
removeempty($('#mydiv'));
function removeempty(parentnode){
var children=$(parentnode).children();
for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
    var text=$(children[i]).text();
    if($.trim(text).length==0){
        $(children[i]).remove();
    }
    else{
        removeempty($(children[i]));
    }
}
return;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter function to get the elements you need instead of trying to find what you don't need.. then clone and add them to your div

```
var x = $('#mydiv *').filter(function(){
   // return elements with a children of img or with some text
   return  $(this).children('img').length || $.trim($(this).text()).length ;
}).clone();
$('#mydiv').html(x);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/5jymK/

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each($("#mydiv").find("span"),function(index,value){
   if($.trim($(value).html()))
   {
        $(value).remove();
   }
});
```

And if you want to remove the breaks, add this before the each statement:

```
$("#mydiv br").remove();
```